# Is there a way to plot most columns of a matrix as one color, but specify several columns to be plotted in unique colors?

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I'm working with a matrix called percs

```
            A        B        C
1931 6.193944 8.978485 4.725187
1932 6.111085 9.266212 4.971554
1933 6.004230 9.300532 5.350349
1934 5.849529 9.285559 5.660330
1935 5.702953 8.996875 5.769253
```

that contains percentages of first names beginning with the column letter in the row year, for all letters A-Z and years 1931-2010. I have a plot of each column together using the following code

```
plot.new()
par(mar=c(5,7,5,3))
matplot(percs, type="l",
        main = "Occurence of First Letters of Names in Females, 1931-2010",
        xlab = "Year",
        ylab = "",
        cex.axis=0.8,
        cex.lab=1.1,
        las=1,
        xaxt="n",
        col="gray")
mtext("Percent of \n All Names", side = 2, line = 2, las =1, cex=1.1)
axis(1, at=seq(1, 80, 10), labels=seq(1931, 2010, 10))
```

I would like to plot most letters in gray, and then specify three letters to be plotted in black and also labeled so the viewer can see which letters stand out. Does anyone know how to specify which columns get colored and labeled? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make multiple calls to `matplot`.

```r
par(mar=c(5,7,5,3))
grays <- c(1,3)
reds <- c(2)
matplot(percs[,grays,drop=FALSE], # updated, subsetting
        type="l",
        main = "Occurence of First Letters of Names in Females, 1931-2010",
        xlab = "Year",
        ylab = "",
        cex.axis=0.8,
        cex.lab=1.1,
        las=1,
        xaxt="n",
        ylim = range(percs),      # NEW
        col="gray")
matplot(percs[,reds,drop=FALSE], type="l", col="red", add=TRUE) # additional call
mtext("Percent of \n All Names", side = 2, line = 2, las =1, cex=1.1)
axis(1, at=seq(1, 80, 10), labels=seq(1931, 2010, 10))
```

[image: multiple matplots with red/gray lines]

The key:

- the first call to `matplot` should set the `ylim=range(percs)`, since otherwise it's likely the to-be-added columns will be outside of the plotting region;
- subsequent calls to `matplot` need nothing more than the data, the `type=`, the new `col=`, and `add=TRUE`; and
- the use of `drop=FALSE` is defensive, in the case that there is only one column selected.

Comment: Hey, sorry about that. Just accepted your answer (I'm pretty sure). Thanks for advice and code help!